# How to assign a Backbone button not belonging to a view, to an action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I know, the title is a bit vague, but let me explain. I'm building a Backbone app with several Views. When I have a button in a view which I want to attach to an action I do something like this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#theDivToPutTheTemplateIn',
    render: function(options) {
        var template = _.template($('#the-template').html(), {});
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
        'click #theButtonToAssign': 'doSomeAction',
    },
    doSomeAction: function(event) {
        alert('Here we do something');
    }
});
```

I now want to bind a button which doesn't belong to any view (it is located in the base html file of the page) to an action. I am tempted to make use of my good friend jQuery again, but I presume that there is a native way of doing this in Backbone.

Does anybody know how I could do this "the backbone way"? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Don't you have some sort of `PageView` which wraps the whole thing?

Comment: @Prinzhorn - Well, the basic html in my page looks like this: `<div id="my-wrapper"><input type="button" id="theButtonToAssign" value="Do something"><p></div>`. I didn't put that into a Backbone View though. Should I? Or do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: I usually have some `PageView` or `AppView` which has `{el: document}`. It bootstraps the app and also allows global event listeners.

Comment: @Prinzhorn - Thanks for your suggestion. I'm still a beginner with all this, so I'm kinda lost in what you mean exactly. Would you have some kind of example code you could share with me?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `PageView` which wraps the whole `document`.

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document,

    events: {
        'click #magic': 'doMagic'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.appView = new AppView({
            model: new Backbone.Model({
                count: 1
            })
        });
    },

    doMagic: function() {
        alert('MAGIC!');
    }
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app',

    template: _.template('<%- count %>'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

        window.setInterval(_.bind(this.tick, this), 1000);

        this.render();
    },

    tick: function() {
        this.model.set('count', this.model.get('count') + 1);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});

var page = new PageView();
```

http://jsbin.com/taviwafa/1/edit